# Sorting mysql results by times from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: `questions`, `articles` and `pictures`

The rows in each table contain a current_timestamp column `posted`, and link to an id. I'd like to sort the results of the rows of all three by their timestamp and only echo the newest of the three (for example: if the question is newest from the ID, display that only)

```
if(count($interests) != 0){ foreach($interests as $interests_following){
    $interestid = mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `interests` WHERE `name` = '$interests_following'"),0);
    $interestquestions = @mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `question_text`, `posted` FROM `questions` WHERE `interest` = '$interests_following'"),0);
    $interestarticles = @mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `article_title`, `posted` FROM `articles` WHERE `interest_id` = '$interestid'"),0);
    $interestpictures = @mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `interest_pic_title`, `posted` FROM `interest_pictures` WHERE `interest_id` = '$interestid'"),0);

echo '.$interests_following.': //<Only display 1 newest item (article/picture/question here>
```

Comment: newest result, so it means you only need 1 result for each table?

Comment: That's the one, for example if the question is newest, only display that in the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT posted 
FROM
(
    SELECT `question_text`, `posted` FROM `questions` 
    WHERE `interest` = '$interests_following'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `article_title`, `posted` FROM `articles` 
    WHERE `interest_id` = '$interestid'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT `interest_pic_title`, `posted` FROM `interest_pictures` 
    WHERE `interest_id` = '$interestid'
) t
ORDER BY posted DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a single row back:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM WHERE `name`='$interests_following' ORDER BY `posted` DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

All of the work is in the SQL

```
ORDER BY `posted` DESC LIMIT 1
```

This orders results to have the newest first, then only return the first row.

If you mean to return only one item out of the 3 tables, you have 2 choices:

- Fetch a row from each and then determine the newest in PHP
- Use a `UNION` to find the single newest row in SQL

The latter makes for less code, but will probably be less readable.

Comment: You will want to avoid `UNION` as it is [expensive](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2969445/41688). `UNION ALL` is cheap.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$interestquestions = @mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `question_text`, `posted` FROM `questions` WHERE `interest` = '$interests_following' ORDER BY timestamp_field DESC limit 1"),0);
```

this will show only the latest data base on your timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

I'll show you the SQL queries so you can see what I did; adapt it to your code as needed.

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT question_text 
     FROM questions ORDER BY posted DESC LIMIT 1 ),

  (SELECT article_title 
    FROM articles ORDER BY posted DESC LIMIT 1 ),

  (SELECT interest_pic_title 
    FROM interest_pictures ORDER BY posted DESC LIMIT 1)
;
```

This sorts by the timestamp DESCending, so the latest record is first, then limits it to the single record. The result will be `question_text, article_title, interest_pic_title`.